# why a typedef (typedef int* pt) can make pt() happen?

Tags: c++

I write the follow codes:

```
typedef int* pt;
pt p = pt();    // compile ok
```

but

```
int* p = (int*)()   // compile fail.
```

I want to figure out why? what is the different between them?

Comment: Is there something else in your code named `pt`?

Comment: `typedef int*p pt;` is not valid...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, extra parentheses are not allowed in the functional cast notation. For example

```
int i1 =  int ();  // compiles
int i2 = (int)();  // doesn't compile
```

But your example will not compile even if you omit the parentheses

```
int* p = int*();   // doesn't compile
```

This is because the functional cast notation requires the type name to either be a *simple-type-specifier* or a *typename-specifier*.

*§5.2.3 [expr.type.conv]*

> *1*   A *simple-type-specifier* (7.1.6.2) or *typename-specifier* (14.6) followed by a parenthesized expression-list constructs a value of the specified type given the expression list. `...`
>   *2*   The expression `T()`, where `T` is a *simple-type-specifier* or *typename-specifier* for a non-array complete object type or the (possibly cv-qualified) `void` type, creates a prvalue of the specified type, whose value is that produced by value-initializing (8.5) an object of type `T`; no initialization is done for the `void()` case.

*simple-type-specifier* basically means a type name consisting of a single word. The following line does not compile for the same reason

```
unsigned int i = unsigned int(); // doesn't compile
```